# compatibility of pdfpages and screenread packages?

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages, incompatibility, preamble

Okay everyone, sorry about my original not being up to standard.  A better version follows.

First, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{screenread}

\begin{document}

Some text

\includepdf{image}

\end{document}
```

File image.pdf can be found here:

http://www.mathematrucker.com/image.pdf

(Any small-sized pdf ought to work.)

File screenread.sty can be found here:

https://github.com/bishboria/screen-read-class

So here's my problem: when `\usepackage{screenread}` is activated, image.pdf disappears from the second page.  My goal is to use `screenread` to shorten the height of the first page without losing image.pdf on the second page.

**Note:** if all I needed to do was merge the second page with the first, there would be no issue.  I think it's okay that my MWE didn't include any links though.

Will leave my initial post below in case it contains any useful information.  It will mean a lot to me if anyone can help me solve this problem!  Thanks everyone.

=======================

Part I of my LaTeX document links to Part II using `pdfpages` and `hyperref`—the former merges individual pdf pages together to create Part II.

Part I has a whitespace issue due to lots of images.  The `screenread` package solves this problem beautifully.

Unfortunately, `screenread` breaks `pdfpages`.  When I try to use both at the same time, Part I still gets created beautifully by `screenread`, but Part II consists of a bunch of empty pages. They have the same width as the Part I pages, but since they don't have any content and `screenread` is still in play, they're only about an inch high.

Ideally there would be some way to "turn `screenread` off" when it comes time to typeset Part II.

Assuming not, can anyone suggest a workaround?  My main problem is getting the hyperlinks into Part I.  Their number is large (>1000), so I'm really dependent on `pdfpages`!  Note that I am using `pdfLaTeX`.

The specific command that's broken is

```
\newcommand{\pdf}[4]{\includepdf[pages={#1},link,noautoscale,offset=#3in #4in]{#2}}
```

Comment: Providing a MWE would help "see" the issue rather than just describing the issue.

Comment: I can't find the `screenread` package...

Comment: Welcome back to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I also can't find the `screenread` package. Where did you get it from?

Comment: @Leucippus, AFAICT it's "\includepdf" that isn't working like normal.  I just now added the specific definition to my question.  (Hopefully that suffices as an "MWE" whatever that means.  "Minimal working example?")

Comment: Admittedly Googling "screenread" (quotes included) isn't quite as quick and easy as clicking a link provided by me, but it's almost as easy.  It's not really a "package" per se, but it's a .sty file.

Comment: No this doesn't suffices. Make a small, complete example starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document} that demonstrates the error. Make *all* resources needed to compile the example available.

Comment: Scratch that...don't go to Google, just enter "screenread" (quotes excluded) in the search box on this page...

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer thank you for providing the explicit request...let me get to that now...be back shortly.

Comment: A search for 'screenread package latex' gives this very page as first entry, and no other useful results. Also please read the [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and the page about [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) if you have still questions what that means.

Comment: @jjdb adding "package latex" to "screenread" was inadvisable, to say the least.

Comment: Took awhile, but after viewing the starter guide and trimming out unessential code I think I have an acceptable version of the question above.  Thank you to everyone for your patience/guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

screenread contains no code to deactivate its settings (but it would be rather easy to extend the package). But you can with the help of geometry restore the "normal" page layout:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\savegeometry{normal}


\usepackage{screenread}

\begin{document}

Some text

\newpage
\loadgeometry{normal}
\EveryShipout{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
              \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}
\includepdf{example-image-letter}

\end{document}
```